# Javascript doesn't run the whole function (JSLInt doesn't mention)

Tags: javascript

I checked my javascript code in jslint.com and jshint.com, it says there are no errors. But for some reason, my code isn't running to what I desire. It seems that either the while statement is not working or it stops after the while statement:

```
      function aMode() {
          
          personData();
          
          if (Enchance1.value == 10) {
             Taken = Taken + (1.25 * EnhanceLevel1.value);
             
          }
          
          if (Enhance1.value == 20) {
             Taken = Taken + (EnhanceLevel1.value * 1.37);
          
          }
          
          if (Enhance2.value == 10) {
             taken2 = t


----------


Taken2 + (1.25 * EnhanceLevel2.value);
             
          }
          
          if (Enhance2.value == 100) {
             Taken2 = Taken2 + (EnhanceLevel2.value * 1.37);
             
          }
          
          while (HP1 <= 0) {
              HP1 = HP1 - Taken2;
              tries1 = tries1 + 1;
    
          }   
          
          while (HP2 <= 0) {
              HP2 = HP2 - Taken1;
              tries2 = tries2 + 1;
    
          }
          
          if (tries1 > tries2) {
              //document.getElementById('personWon').innerHTML = person1.value;
              alert(person1.value + "won!");
          } else if (tries1 < tries2) {
              //document.getElementById('personWon').innerHTML = person2.value;
              alert(person2.value + "won!");
          }
          
          //alert("test"); <- test
      }
```

The problem is, when, in HTML, it runs the function by the button, it only runs from the if statements to the first while statement. I know this since I put `alert("test")` at the end to see if it runs the whole code. I know I spelled the function correctly since, if I put `alert("test")` at the beginning, it works. Here's the code for the button: `<button id="typeMode" onclick="aMode()">Click me!</button>`. More specifically, it is in a div with a certain class. Another thing I put was "use strict;" on the first line of my javascript code.

Am I using the wrong syntax? Is it because I forgot to put a semi-colon ';' or something?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `alert()` statements only run under specific conditions.  Maybe those conditions aren't met?  `while` loops also only run under specific conditions.  Step through this in a debugger and see what the actual runtime behavior is and what the runtime values of the variables are.  "It doesn't run the whole function" is kind of a non-starter.  It's running exactly the code it's told to run.

Comment: But either one of the last two if statements must be met. Either if player1 won or player2 won.

Comment: Unless `hits1 == hits2`, in which case neither condition is met.  This is why debugging works a lot better than guessing and assuming.

Comment: try to alert HP1 or HP2

Comment: @David I never put "=="

Comment: @Christian: Yes, that would be the exact point I just made.

Comment: aside: lint and hint don't check for errors, that's not their point, at all.

Comment: @dandavis then what does?

Comment: @Christian: Well, jshint *does* check for syntax errors.  But they definitely don't check for errors in your logic.

Comment: those tools check for things developers do that _could_ be un-indeded, like explixit globals, poor form, etc; style mistakes. The runtime/console checks for actual errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loops are running if the `HP` is **less than** or equal to `0`. You probably want to swap the comparison around.

```
  while (HP1 >= 0) {
      HP1 = HP1 - damageTaken2;
      hits1 = hits1 + 1;

  }   

  while (HP2 >= 0) {
      HP2 = HP2 - damageTaken1;
      hits2 = hits2 + 1;

  }

  if (hits1 > hits2) {
      //document.getElementById('playerWon').innerHTML = player1.value;
      alert(player1.value + "won!");
  } else if (hits1 < hits2) {
      //document.getElementById('playerWon').innerHTML = player2.value;
      alert(player2.value + "won!");
  } else {
      alert("draw!");
  }
```

Comment: My editor ignores loops...XD But thanks! Lemme try it out

Comment: Okay...so i tried it out but it doesn't do anything.....see; Output: none... even if I put alert at the end.

Comment: i think this is the right answer. if HP1 is more than 0 the loop will be skipped. If HP1 is less than or equal 0 the loop will run indefinitely. spapping comparison fixes that

Comment: @Christian As mentioned in the comments, your alert will only happen if the number of hits is _different_. You might want to put a last `else` statement to say that the duel was a draw.

Comment: @thgaskell I'm trying to make their weapons different (part of my HTML Code): Sword vs Shovel. But I ran it (with the else) and it didn't work. It didn't run the if, elseif or else... -_- I even changed the HP and it didn't work... EDIT: Is it about the "use strict;"? EDIT 2: Removed "use strict" and didn't work (not in the code i put in)

Comment: I would also double check that `hits1` and `hits2` are being initialized to `0` as well. `undefined + 1` will result in `NaN`.

Comment: I put .value to the end of HP1 and HP2 and i saw that i defined hits1 and hits2. It doesn't show any alerts, even if I didn't define it, it doesn't show NaN or something. ***EDIT***: It was really damageTaken, not damageTaken1... so lemme test it first **EDIT 2**: Didnt work nvm then